# How do I insert a variable into a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, quotes

I have looked for some responses on the web, but none of them are very accurate.

I want to be able to do this:

```
$id = "" . $result ["id"] . "";
$info = array('$id','Example');

echo $info[0];
```

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you need is (not recommended):

```
$info = array("$id",'Example'); // variable interpolation happens in ""
```

or just

```
$info = array($id,'Example'); // directly use the variable, no quotes needed
```

You've enclosed the variable inside single quotes and inside single quotes variable interpolation does not happen and `'$id'` is treated as a string of length three where the first character is a dollar.

Answer (score 5):

Just don't put it in quotes:

```
$id = $result["id"];
$info = array($id, 'Example');
echo $info[0];
```

Alternatively, if you use double quotes rather than single quotes, then it will be interpolated (which also results in it being converted to a string):

```
$id = $result["id"];
$info = array("$id", 'Example');
echo $info[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can store variables within arrays, though you'll need to remove the space between `$result` and the opening bracket.

```
$foo = $result["bar"]; // assuming value of 'bar'

$collection = array( $foo, "fizz" );

foreach ( $collection as $item ) {
  // bar, fizz
  echo $item;
}
```